# Does bike geometry or wheel affect maximum cog size?

Tags: shimano, cassette, derailleur-rear

I got a used Cannondale Super X 105 during the winter and when I was getting it ready for the summer, I couldn't index the rear derailleur properly. It wouldn't shift to the largest cog and shifting to the smallest cog was iffy. I took it in to a bike shop to get it looked at (full tune-up while at it) and the feedback was that the cassette (11/34 I think) was too big for the bike and the derailleur was too small (plus bent cage which I suspected). Tried to see if I could keep the cassette and get a larger derailleur but the mechanic insisted the cassette is not right and would need replacement. Maximum I'd be able to put on would be a 30T.

I've searched online to see if frame size limits your maximum cog size but couldn't find anything. So now I'm wondering if he was simply assuming I would want a same for same replacement of the bent derailleur.
I already spent almost $200 replacing all bearings and BB  (total blindside there) which was what I had budgeted for the drive train so I don't want to spend money I don't have to.

Comment: You can read the rear mech's part number off the engraving, often on the underside.  Will be of the format "RD-xxxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the frame size doens't limit your cassette choice.  Within reason any 700c wheeled bike should take any available cassette size.

**What matters most is the Derailleur's capabilities.**   The maximum and minimum tooth count is a published value for each derailleur model.
Also in the stats are other useful values.

Presuming your bike is a 2017, it would have had a "Shimano 105 GS" rear mech.  (from https://99spokes.com/bikes/cannondale/2017/superx-105)

This might be the RD-5800-GS which is documented at https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/105-5800/RD-5800-GS.html

| Item | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Low sprocket_Max. | 32T |
| Low sprocket_Min. | 28T |
| Max. front difference | 16T |
| Top sprocket_Max. | 12T |
| Top sprocket_Min. | 11T |
| Total capacity | 37T |

So nominally this combination would take a largest cog with 28/30/32 tooth.  The smallest is 11 or 12T, so it wouldn't work well if the little cog was a 14, and probably jamb up on a 16T.

Shimano's specs are notoriously conservative, so this combo probably runs fine on 34T but would be nominally "out of spec"

---

That said, there might be something special about your bike which the mechanic has noticed, but not come across in the text of your question.  Adding a photo might help.

Comment: Thanks @Criggie. I've since taken the bike for a few rides and I really only had problems whenever I accidentally cross chained.
I did check the derailleur model which is shown on the body and it's an RD-R7000. It's odd how they don't seem to add what size it is but from comparing it to the images on the website, my cage looks long and has a bit of an angle similar to the GS. I've taken some photos but they are to large to upload from my phone so I'll see if I can get them up later.

Comment: @TamTam that model is rated for 28-34 tooth biggest cog in the GS model, whereas the SS model only rated up to a 30T maximum.  Could be your bike guy doesn't like big dinner-plate sized low gears ?  It should be fine.